# Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

Tags: javascript

```
  function total_card(){
  apex.server.process("P500596_TOTAL_CARDS", {
        x01: '',
        pageItems: '#P500596_DESDE,#P500596_HASTA,#P500596_BU,#P500596_CANAL,#P500596_TERRITORIO,#P500596_AGENCIA,#P500596_OFICIAL,#P500596_PUESTO_OFICIAL,#P500596_GESTION,#P500596_TIPO_DE_AUTOGESTION'
   
    },{
        async: true,
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend: function() {
                     
        },
        
        success: function(data){
            
               var json = eval("(" + data + ")");
               var email = json.filter( element => element.tipo =="EMAIL")
               var sms = json.filter( element => element.tipo =="SMS");
               document.getElementById('card-total1').innerHTML = sms[0].cantidad;
               document.getElementById('card-total2').innerHTML = email[0].cantidad;
        }
    });

}
   

  function grafico_diario(){
  apex.server.process("500596_AUTOGESTION_DIARIO", {
        x01: '',
        pageItems: '#P500596_DESDE,#P500596_HASTA,#P500596_BU,#P500596_CANAL,#P500596_TERRITORIO,#P500596_AGENCIA,#P500596_OFICIAL,#P500596_PUESTO_OFICIAL,#P500596_GESTION,#P500596_TIPO_DE_AUTOGESTION'
   
    },{
        async: true,
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend: function() {
                     
        },
        
        success: function(data) {
               var json = eval("(" + data + ")");
               console.log(json);
               var dia = [];
               var cant = [];
               
               for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                   dia.push(json[i].dia);
                   cant.push(parseFloat(json[i].cantidad));

        }
    }); ------------------ ****aqui me brinda el error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'****

}


               Highcharts.chart('grafico_diario', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'line'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Grafico Diario Mensajes de Autogestión'
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Total enviados diariamente.'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: dia
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total Gestiones Enviadas'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    line: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        enableMouseTracking: false
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Mensajes',
                    data: cant
                }]
            });
```

Comment: qué estás haciendo? en qué linea da el error?

Comment: estoy llamando una funcion en apex con javascript , sin embargo tengo problema con eso del corchete o coma me marca error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' en la segunda funcion , nose que estoy fallando

Comment: Este tipo de errores ocurren cuando esperas un JSON, pero desde el servidor emites un JSON no válido. ¿Cuál es el código de servidor que procesa tu llamada? Debes revisar allí, para garantizar que la única salida en ese contexto es un JSON válida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te faltaba cerrar el `for{}`.

```
function grafico_diario(){
    apex.server.process("500596_AUTOGESTION_DIARIO", {
        x01: '',
        pageItems: '#P500596_DESDE,#P500596_HASTA,#P500596_BU,#P500596_CANAL,#P500596_TERRITORIO,#P500596_AGENCIA,#P500596_OFICIAL,#P500596_PUESTO_OFICIAL,#P500596_GESTION,#P500596_TIPO_DE_AUTOGESTION'
    },
    {
        async: true,
        dataType: "text",
        beforeSend: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            var json = eval("(" + data + ")");
            console.log(json);
            var dia = [];
            var cant = [];               
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                dia.push(json[i].dia);
                cant.push(parseFloat(json[i].cantidad));
            } // <-- Faltaba
        }
    });
}
```

El `Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token` se debe a un error de tipeo, en este caso no esperaba un `)` más bien esperaba un `}`